# How do I prevent a segmentation fault from stopping my node.js script?

Tags: node.js, segmentation-fault

Recently I've run into a couple of separate issues ([this one](https://github.com/creationix/node-gamepad/issues/15) and [this one](https://github.com/kelly/node-i2c/issues/13) specifically) where a segmentation fault occurs and it kills the running Node.js script. While the ultimate goal is to resolve these issues to prevent segment faults from occurring, the issues I linked to are still open. I'm looking for a solution to allow a script handle the error with potential to recover.

Example outputs (which don't give error output beyond this):

`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

`Segmentation fault: 11` (it's been a while since testing this one, could vary slightly)

Try/catch techniques don't seem to be effective so far. In the case of the linked modules, it's a bit tougher to test/share as extra hardware is involved (I can still post some code if it will help).

In general, is there a good technique to prevent a segmentation fault from stopping my node.js script? So far I've only run into this issue intermittently with modules that access external hardware.

Comment: You can't.  A seg fault is somewhere in native code and you can't catch it via Javascript.  Even if you could, you have no idea what state your server is in after a seg fault so you can't really continue unless the error is caught right in the context where it occurred and that code can cleanly put things back in a good state.  The problem needs to be fixed in the native code where it occurs.

Comment: @jfriend00 Understood. If you add it as an answer I will mark it as the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In general, is there a good technique to prevent a segmentation fault from stopping my node.js script?

You can't. A seg fault is somewhere in native code and you can't catch it via Javascript. Even if you could, you have no idea what state your server is in after a seg fault so you can't really continue unless the error is caught right in the context where it occurred and that code can cleanly put things back in a good state.

The problem needs to be fixed in the native code where it occurs.